# How to get only the matched text in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code in Python

```
import psutil
import re

_list = psutil.get_pid_list()

for i in _list:
    if i > 0:
        _process_path = psutil.Process(i).exe
        _match = re.search('\/Applications\/.*\.app\/',_process_path)
        if _match:
            print _process_path
```

It works and here is an example of what it returns:

```
/Applications/RegExr.app/Contents/MacOS/RegExr
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/24.0.1312.57/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper
/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/Helpers/Crash Reporter.app/Contents/Helpers/crash-catcher
/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/Activity Monitor
/Applications/AppCleaner.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/AppCleaner Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/AppCleaner Helper
/Applications/Transmit.app/Contents/MacOS/TransmitMenu.app/Contents/MacOS/TransmitMenu
/Applications/Twitter.app/Contents/MacOS/Twitter
/Applications/ScreenFlow.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenFlowHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenFlowHelper
```

How do I make it so that it only returns this instead?

```
/Applications/RegExr.app
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/Helpers/Crash Reporter.app
/Applications/TextWrangler.app
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app
/Applications/AppCleaner.app
/Applications/Transmit.app
/Applications/Twitter.app
/Applications/ScreenFlow.app
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `_match` object can return the matched text as `_match.group(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Print the matched group instead, using the [`MatchObject.group()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
print _match.group()
```